# What might def manyApp = xs => xs in scala?

Tags: scala

`def manyApp = xs=>xs` is part of a class definition in Scala and was wondering what the purpose of a function that maps to itself is?

*just learning scala and the terminology i use might not be correct.

Comment: It's common enough that there's such a function predefined: `identity`. You'll need to look at where `manyApp` is used to understand its purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function such as `A => A` is a useful default implementation for a method in a trait or base class that wants to have inert behavior that is overridable by implementors.

Whether that is the intent with `manyApp` depends on how it is used.